# Record elements compared in sorting algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, insertion-sort

Hi I am using the following insertion sort algorithm and I would like to record the elements being compared. Basically I want the comparisons to be stored in two array lists, arrList1 and arrList2. If an element is in its correct place then both array lists will have the same element. If its not then arrList1 will have the chosen element and arrayList2 will have the element its comparing itself to. I am currently struggling to do this, so I was wondering if anyone can help? Thanks

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> arrList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> arrList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
        public static void insertSort(int[] A){
      for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
        int value = A[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && A[j] > value){
          A[j + 1] = A[j];
          j = j - 1;
        }
        A[j + 1] = value;
      }
    }
```

EDIT:
For example: If my array had the numbers 1,3,2,4,6,5 then when comparing, this is how I want my two array lists to look:

```
       arrList1    arrList2
#1        1           1
#2        3           3
#3        2           3 (As 2 goes before 3 then it must be compared to 3)
#4        4           4
#5        6           6
#6        5           6 (As 5 is lower then 6 then it must be compared to 6)
```

Sorted array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

As you can see, arrList1 is basically the order of the input array whilst arrList2 is the element it compares to if its not in correct position. If its in correct position then arrList 2 will be same value.

Comment: I am not quite sure with what you mean with your question... Could you maybe give us an example as in... So if A = this, then I would expect arrList1 to be that and arrList2 to be that... Maybe with the example you will get more answers

Comment: It is now editted to make it more clearer

Comment: Can anyone help please? I have added a clearer description.

Comment: Alright.. taking a look now...

Comment: Check my answer now... ses if that's what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have...

```
public class Test {
    public static List<Integer> arrList1;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> arrList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main (String... args){
        Integer[] toSort = {1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5};


        arrList1 = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(toSort, toSort.length));
        insertSort(toSort);

        List<Integer> sortedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int aux: toSort){
            sortedArray.add(aux);
        }

        System.out.println("Array list 1: " + arrList1);
        System.out.println("Array list 2: " + arrList2);
        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + sortedArray);
    }

    public static void insertSort(Integer[] A){
        arrList2.add(arrList1.get(0));
        for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
            int value = A[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            if ((j >= 0 && A[j] > value)){
                arrList2.add(A[j]);
            }else{
                arrList2.add(A[i]);
            }
            while(j >= 0 && A[j] > value){
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }

            A[j + 1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code for me is:

Array list 1: [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]
Array list 2: [1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6]
Sorted array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: now that I understand the question here is what I propose. First note that insert sort has sqare(O(n^2)) complexity so another computation of the same complexity will not change the overall complexity of the algorithm. So here is what you do - first you compute the values in arrList2 by traversing all values on the left of the current element and search for the first one greater then the current element. The second phase is simply the sorting algorithm - as you already pointed out arrList1 holds the sorted A. The whole thing could be implemented with better complexity but not using insert sort.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> arrList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> arrList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
public static void insertSort(int[] A){
  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
    boolean found_greater = false;
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
      if (A[j] > A[i]) {
        found_greater = true;
        arrList2.add(A[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found_greater) {
      arrList2.add(A[i]);
    }
  }

  for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
    int value = A[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while(j >= 0 && A[j] > value){
      A[j + 1] = A[j];
      j = j - 1;
    }

    arrList1.add(A[i]);
    A[j + 1] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, how about this case 8,7,6,2 Here 2 is greater then all the previous elements so which one should be in arrList2? Is it the first one on the left(i.e. 6). Am I getting this right - in arrList2 you either have the element or the first one on it's left that is bigger then it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. arrList1 will display 2 and arrList2 will display the numbers it is comparing to. So for your example when we get to 2, arrList2 will have the first one on the left thats bigger. This will keep happening until 2 is in its correct place

Comment: I have changed my answer to reflect the actual question. Hope it helps.